# How to use http 'POST' with form-data body instead of json body? (Angular2/Typescript)

Tags: json, http, angular, typescript

I have some request I want to perform, and until now I used the http.post with json's like this:

```
this.http.post("https://somepath.com/users/login", JSON.stringify({"email": "someone@gmail.com","password":"123","user_token":"sss"}), RequestOptionsArgs);
```

but this won't work since this request to this website needs to be form-data body...how can I take this same call and change it to be form-data?

thanks!

Comment: try removing `JSON.stringify(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i can see in [Angular 2 tests](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/test/backends/xhr_backend_spec.ts#L318) you should use FormData object. ie:

```
let body = new FormData();
body.append('email', 'someone@gmail.com');
body.append('password', '123');
this.http.post("https://somepath.com/users/login", body);
```

Comment: Here I can get the status as 200 Ok. But from using this how can I redirect to another page?